# NCDC Web Services weather data with REST and PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl, weather, noaa

I am trying to read precipitation data from the [National Climatic Data Center's online web services](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2) with PHP, but I can't figure out how to read it.  The documentation says that it is a RESTful web service.  I have gotten a token, and I have tried everything I can think of and searched the web for any suggestions I could find, but I can't get it to return anything.  My first step is to use the web service to request a list of datasets, so I know what dataset to use when I request the actual data.  Here is the code I have been using to try to request the datasets.  Can anybody steer me in the right direction to read the results.

```
$url = "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets?stationid=COOP:010957";
$curl_post_data = array("token" => $token);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/json','Content-length: '.strlen($curl_post_data)));
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$json_a = json_decode($curl_response,TRUE);
var_dump($json_a); // just to see the structure.
echo "\n";
foreach($json_a as $row){
   echo $row->status;
   echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: You should be looking at `var_dump($curl_response)` instead. In my case it's giving me a 500 error from the server. There may be a problem with the request that you sent to the server. I'm assuming in my case it's just because of the token, but that may be your issue. Also check `json_last_error_msg()`. Don't just assume the JSON parser succeeded. There may be a problem with the json the server sends back as well. Apart from that I don't see that you have a PHP issue here. Nothing we can fix in your code anyway. You will need to refer to the API's docs and support.

Comment: Or maybe try using http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html much more simpler and OOP based and it will help with debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that API V2, which the above link describes, has been deprecated, and they reverted to [API V1](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/support/access-data-service-api-user-documentation).  Too bad they didn't bother to remove the V2 documentation from the web.  V1 does not require a token, so the data retrieval is very easy (after you figure out the correct station IDs and Datasets).  Here is my new code that works:

```
$string = file_get_contents("https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=local-climatological-data&stations=72509014739&units=standard&startDate=2020-02-01&endDate=2020-02-12&format=json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, TRUE);
foreach($json_a as $item){
    echo $item['DATE'] . " " . $item['HourlyDryBulbTemperature'] . "F, " . $item['HourlyPrecipitation'] . "in</br>";
}
```